# Horizontal scroll AND vertical scroll in the same page

Tags: html, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Is it possible to enable vertical scroll WITH MOUSE WHEEL in the same page?
I'd like to Scroll a page normally, but in some `#div's` i'd like to scroll horizontally.

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sw5Lybsm/

[image]

I've tried many things and searched the whole internet, but no succes :(

Comment: Can you provide the code which you have worked on.

Comment: JQuery has a plugin for this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: You can implement it using `mousewheel` event, however this thing is not part of the standard so I would not rely on it

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to post the code here...   I have a jsfiddle here: https://goo.gl/X0cB6Y   and a example image here http://i.imgur.com/T3NIMKc.png  .

Comment: @Andry it doesn't work for me because don't want the whole page to be vertical scrolling, only a div.

Comment: EDIT: i'm trying in another way: creating a vertical scroll box but turning it 90 degress... i'll work more in it and post result here later   https://jsfiddle.net/xbLgfpg8/

Comment: When I see your Fiddle, I found that there's a vertical scroll for the whole page, and horizontal scrolls for the images divs. So I don't get what your real question is?

Comment: @ayadibaha if you try to scroll with the mouse cursor above the images, you won't scroll horizontally, but vertically. scrolling by clicking the bar works, but I want to scroll only using mousewheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used the jquery library suggested in this link :

[CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

And I got it to work vertically and horizontally:

Here's A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/sw5Lybsm/3/)

I just used this code after including the jquery file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#scroll").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });
    $("#scroll1").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });
    $("#scroll2").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });
    $("#scroll3").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });
});
```

And It wasn't able to work on all the elements with the same id="scroll", so I renamed the next scroll divs to #scroll1,#scroll2...etc, and added them into CSS as well.

I hope this will be what you're looking for.

Comment: OMG, THAT'S IT! Almost cried here !  Thanks a lot !  Hope your answer help many people around the world :D    YAYYYYYYYYY!

Comment: i'm still having issue... on jsfiddle my code works very well, but when I try to run from my computer, the script don't run. I already loaded in HTML the same external resource that JSFiddle run: ** <script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> **  and tried also **  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js  ** ... here's the full code: https://jsbin.com/hanezokine/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I think you forgot to add the jquery library, put it the first one, before any other script tag : `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` , and you can try it here with your link, i changed it : [fixed](https://jsbin.com/ruzawumigi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: [link] `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script src="horizontalscroll.js"></script>`  -  YES! YEEEEEES!  at first after your help I can't make it work, but I added my js in the html and now, finally, woks 100% !  Thanks! sorry for bothering you and my bad english xD